# Selenium Python 3, Chrome incognito closing cookie popup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am giving up, been trying to start making my own program that sources different Information from websites, and places them into one Tkinter interface.
My Problem now is that after opening up googlemaps and inserting a placename, I can't do anything anymore. Have tried to fix this for the last 8hours, with different fixes from different sources, nothing helps.
Chrome Incognito opens a cookie pop up and xpaths arent being found.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from tkinter import *
import time


search_Input = ('Bosruck')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Green/Dropbox/Coding/Skitouren_app/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
google_maps = browser.get("https://www.google.com/maps/")
search_bar = browser.find_element_by_id("searchboxinput")
search_bar.send_keys(search_Input)
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

browser.implicitly_wait(10)

accept_cookies = browser.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton")
accept_cookies.click()

search_nearby = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/jsl/div[3]/div[9]/div[8]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div[3]")
search_nearby.click()
```

Error code:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="introAgreeButton"]"}
(Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)

Pop up: (According to the code it's actually a Widget)

```
<div class="fkimef I47yTd k8Lt0"><div jscontroller="s0BsG"><div class="kv8HMe"><div class="A5gc2" role="banner"><img src="//www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_92x36dp.png" srcset="//www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x36dp.png 2x" width="92" height="36" class="xxARHf" alt="" role="presentation" data-atf="true" data-iml="1770.5100000021048"><div class="qu2wBd"><div jscontroller="hZ9Bt" jsaction="JIbuQc:UEmoBd;LEpEAf:hbfrge;" class="biMIl " data-url="https://consent.google.com/intro/?continue=https://www.google.com/maps&amp;origin=https://www.google.com&amp;if=1&amp;gl=AT&amp;hl=en&amp;pc=m&amp;uxe=4423402" data-lc="en"><div role="button" class="U26fgb c7fp5b FS4hgd" jscontroller="iSvg6e" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;;keydown:I481le;" jsshadow="" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-alignright="true" data-aligntop="true" id="ow6" __is_owner="true"><div class="lVYxmb MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><div class="g4jUVc" aria-hidden="true"></div><span jsslot="" class="I3EnF oJeWuf"><span class="NlWrkb snByac"><div class="ZbVuDb">English<img src="//www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/keyboard_arrow_down_grey600_24dp.png" srcset="//www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/2x/keyboard_arrow_down_grey600_24dp.png 2x" width="24" height="24" class="B4rYNe" data-atf="true" data-iml="1771.0650000008172"></div></span></span></div></div><div class="PhmSnf"><div role="presentation" class="U26fgb O0WRkf oG5Srb C0oVfc" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;" jsshadow="" aria-disabled="false"><a class="FKF6mc TpQm9d" href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&amp;continue=https://www.google.com/maps&amp;gae=cb-4423402" target="_top"><div class="Vwe4Vb MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><div class="ZFr60d CeoRYc"></div><span jsslot="" class="CwaK9"><span class="RveJvd snByac"><div class="CdmNIf">Sign in</div></span></span></a></div></div></div></div><div class="n8WZGd"><img src="//www.gstatic.com/ac/cb/cb_cbu_kickin.svg" width="360" height="120" aria-hidden="true" data-atf="true" data-iml="1779.9700000032317"></div><h1 class="DP1T8c">Before you continue</h1><div class="PNgVMb">Google uses <a href="https://policies.google.com/technologies/cookies?hl=en" target="_blank">cookies</a> and other data to deliver, maintain, and improve our services and ads. If you agree, we’ll personalize the content and ads you see based on your activity on Google services like Search, Maps, and YouTube. We also have <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy/google-partners?hl=en" target="_blank">partners</a> that measure how our services are used. Click “See more” to review your options or visit <a href="https://g.co/privacytools" target="_blank">g.co/privacytools</a> anytime.</div></div><div class="OvJdSb UTd6ef" tabindex="0" role="navigation" jsname="c6xFrd"><div role="presentation" class="U26fgb O0WRkf oG5Srb HQ8yf C0oVfc wtr0xd" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;" jsshadow="" jsname="OCpkoe" aria-disabled="false"><a class="FKF6mc TpQm9d" href="./ui/?continue=https://www.google.com/maps&amp;origin=https://www.google.com&amp;if=1&amp;gl=AT&amp;hl=en&amp;pc=m&amp;uxe=4423402" aria-label="See more about your choices for cookies and other data"><div class="Vwe4Vb MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><div class="ZFr60d CeoRYc"></div><span jsslot="" class="CwaK9"><span class="RveJvd snByac">See more</span></span></a></div><form action="https://consent.google.com/set?pc=m&amp;uxe=4423402" method="post" class="A28uDc" jsaction="JIbuQc:tQDWEc"><div role="button" id="introAgreeButton" class="U26fgb O0WRkf oG5Srb HQ8yf C0oVfc wtr0xd ic02He M9Bg4d j7nIZb" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;j9grLe:.CLIENT;HUObcd:.CLIENT" jsshadow="" jsname="higCR" aria-label="Agree to the use of cookies and other data for the purposes described" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" data-response-delay-ms="5"><div class="Vwe4Vb MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd" style="top: 11.2344px; left: 24.7656px; width: 91px; height: 91px;"></div><div class="ZFr60d CeoRYc"></div><span jsslot="" class="CwaK9"><span class="RveJvd snByac">I agree</span></span></div><input type="hidden" name="continue" value="https://www.google.com/maps"><input type="hidden" name="cc" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="t1" value="ADw3F8hKEVTwGq2L_SO4Xmc-ath5RgT4LA:1611765655866"><input type="hidden" name="x" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="v" value="AT.en+V9+BX" jsname="UDNScf"><input type="hidden" name="if" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="origin" value="https://www.google.com"><input type="hidden" name="gl" value="AT"></form></div></div></div>
```

[This is the Pop up I am getting that makes it impossible for me to make use of anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNcoB.png)

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the cookie popup.

Comment: I commented out the 2 lines with `accept_cookie` and the script your posted ran without errors. I am also not seeing a popup for accept cookies.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I always get the same Pop up telling me to accept cookies "Before you Continue......"

Comment: @Jortega it is a GDPR related EU thing that is why it did not appear for you in the USA :)

Answer (score 0):

If you open `<jsl jstcache="86">` then you'll see that the 'agree button' you would like to click is inside an `iframe`. To interact the iframe contents, you need to tell your driver to switch to it (and later to switch back).

In practice:

```py
consent_iframe = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="widget-consent-frame"]')
browser.switch_to.frame(consent_iframe)
```

After that `browser.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton")` will work like a charm and you may click the 'accept' button. Don't forget to switch back to the default frame where you came from with `browser.switch_to.default_content()`.